# Losing javascript which is added into pdf using itext

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying to add javascript into a pdf using itext and later merge it with another pdf. 
But the final merged pdf does not contain the javascript. The javascript is working fine if the pdf is not merged with another pdf.

**Merging code :** 
    FileOutputStream sectionR = new FileOutputStream(RESULT);

```
PdfCopyFields copier = new PdfCopyFields(sectionR);

 for (String curInPath : listFile) {

       PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(curInPath);
        copier.addDocument(reader);

      }

   copier.close();
```

I tried to add JS to the resulting merged pdf, but it is not taking it. I guess its not editable.

**Below is the code adding JS to pdf which is not merged yet.**

```
FileOutputStream section1Pdf = new FileOutputStream("newPDFSection");

PdfReader readerSection1 = new PdfReader("Existing PDF - Section 1");

PdfStamper stamperSection1 = new PdfStamper(readerSection1,section1Pdf);

stamperSection1.addJavaScript(
"var nameField = this.getField('txtOwnerCity');" +              "nameField.setAction('Keystroke'," +"'forceUpperCase()');" +
      "" +"function forceUpperCase(){" +
"if(!event.willCommit)event.change = " +
"event.change.toUpperCase();" +
"}");
```

When I tried adding JS to the resulting merged pdf, it does not allow me saying it is not editable anymore.

This is how I am trying to add

```
FileOutputStream sectionR = new FileOutputStream(RESULT);

            PdfCopyFields copier = new PdfCopyFields(sectionR);


            for (String curInPath : listFile) {

                PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(curInPath);
                copier.addDocument(reader);             
}
copier.close();

PdfReader readersectionResult = new PdfReader("result.pdf");

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(readersectionResult, new FileOutputStream("newResult.pdf"));

stamper.addJavaScript(some JS);
```

The error I am getting is ' WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.'

I am not sure if I am doing it right above, All I am trying to do is get pdfstamper of resulting pdf to add new JS to it.

**When I am trying to edit form filed values, it says not editable anymore.**

AcroFields acro= stamper .getAcroFields();

acro.setField("txtOfficerName"+officerChar,officerSO.getFullName());

Comment: Please provide the merging code and a sample document. Many people have found wrong sample code for merging documents using iText on the net which loses much information. Furthermore document level JS code may be lost in merging routines as most of them import pages from other documents but not document level characteristics.

Comment: I added the merging code. In that code I am trying to add all the pdfs into the copier of the final pdf. But how do I provide a smaple document...I am not sure....

Comment: You can provide a sample document by means of a file hoster with the option of sharing, e.g. dropbox or google drive, and post the link here. BTW, using one of the `Pdf*Copy*` family of classes is a good start. This at least copies JS associated with form fields.

Comment: Yes PDF Copy is copying the JS associated using adobe. But JS that is associated using itext is gone. Is the sample doc really important as I am not sure if I can share it.

Comment: Alternatively also add the code with which you add the JS to the PDF using iText.

Comment: I added the code where I am adding JS to the existing pdf before merging.

Comment: Ok, you definitively have to add that js explicitly to the result PDF.  *When I tried adding JS to the resulting merged pdf, it does not allow me saying it is not editable anymore.* can you post the exact stack trace of that error?

Comment: I added the code.....the problem I am having is retreiving the pdfstamper of resulting pdf.....i do not know how to do it.

Comment: **1.** *WARNING: Cannot set header. Response already committed.* That sounds like you are programming something like a `Servlet` and try to set some header after you wrote some result body content. I especially doubt it is an iText message. **2.** *When I am trying to edit form filed values, it says not editable anymore.* That sounds like you use Adobe Reader-enabled files. They have to be treated with special care, otherwise the Reader-enabling breaks. You especially (in the context of iText) may only manipulate it in a `PdfStamper` created in append mode. Importing pages from it breaks it.

Comment: I need help with th second scenario. Yes I am uisng Adobe-enabled files. Is there a way to get PdfStamper of an existing pdf without creating a new output stream?

Comment: A PdfStamper requires an output stream or an output file.  Depending on the PdfReader constructor you use, though, you can replace the old file in place.

Comment: Concerning your Reader-enabled files... If I understand section 12.8.2.3 in the [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) on usage right signatures (Reader-enabling is implemented by means of such signatures) correctly, Reader-enabling is broken if A) the signature doesn't match the signed content anymore or B) the changes done to the document are of different types than the ones explicitly allowed by Reader-enabling. As adding pages from other document is never allowed, you cannot merge PDFs and keep the result Reader-enabled.

Comment: OK. Thanks. I am able to add JS to a new pdf but I cannot change acrofields of it. But I guess I can handle it. Thanks again for your patience and research.